# finding if a function between function spaces is surjective

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

let $ A,B,C $     be sets and  $ \quad f:A\rightarrow B \quad$ an injective function and $\quad \Phi : C^B\rightarrow C^A \quad$   s.t $\quad \Phi(g) = g\circ f \quad $      be a function,

prove that $\Phi $  is surjective

$f$ injective $\therefore \exists h\in B^A : h\circ f = id_A$

if $ \Phi$ is not surjective $ \exists g\in C^A :  \Phi^{-1} (g) = \emptyset \implies \nexists  i \in C^B : f\circ i=g  \qquad $ this is one of the many attempts i have done, i also tried using the definition of injectivity, i tried to suppose that $\Phi$ has no right inverse but i always get stuck and i don't know how to continue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not true: let $A=C=\emptyset$ and $B=\{x\}$ the one-element set. Then $C^B=\emptyset$ but $A^B=\{\mathrm{id}_\emptyset\}$, so $C^B\to C^A$ cannot be surjective.

Answer (score 0):

Think about this at a high level: $\Phi$ being surjective means that it can output any possible function $h : A \to C$. That is, for any function $h : A \to C$, there exists a function $g : B \to C$ such that $h = g \circ f$.

Now, $g$ can be any map, but $f$ is some given fixed map. For any $a \in A$, it has to map $a$ to $f(a)$. So in some sense, $g$ is on their own. They have to figure out how to 'freely' map $f(a) \in B$ to $h(a) \in C$ for every $a \in A$. Now, if we have any $b_1, b_2 \in B$, then so long as $b_1 \neq b_2$, $g$ can 'freely' map $g(b_1)$ and $g(b_2)$ into any pair of elements in $C$. So the only issue that may arise is that if there are a pair of distinct elements $a_1 \neq a_2 \in A$ such that $f(a_1) = f(a_2)$. In that case, $g(f(a_1)) = g(f(a_2))$. Thus $g \circ f$ would have to always map $a_1$ and $a_2$ to the same element, regardless of what $g$ is. Thankfully, such a situation would never arise. (Why is that?)